# Is there any limitation to store data in Realm?

Tags: ios, realm

Please suggest me ,is it better to store data using Realm and is there any limitation for data storing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No limitation on how much data to be stored. It only depends on the Hard disk size.

Answer (score 6):

[Limitations](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#general) from the official documentation:

- The upper limit of class names is 57 characters. Realm for Android prepend class_ to all names, and the browser will show it as part of the name.
- The length of field names has a upper limit of 63 character.
  Nested transactions are not supported, and an exception is thrown if they are detected.
- Strings and byte arrays (byte[]) cannot be larger than 16 MB

---

- Sorting and case insensitive string matches in queries are only supported for character sets in ‘Latin Basic’, ‘Latin Supplement’, ‘Latin Extended A’, ‘Latin Extended B’ (UTF-8 range 0-591). In addition, setting the case insensitive flag in queries when using equalTo(), contains(), endsWith() or beginsWith() will only work on characters from the English locale.

---

The only limitation that I find iffy is that [you still can't store `List<Integer>` or `List<String>` (list of primitives)](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/575), you have to make a RealmObject that contains the value (`RealmList<TelephoneNumber>` for example), or store the list in a String field.

---

The primitive list limitation will be removed by realm-core 3.0.0 and realm-java 4.0.0.